# SMC Tigerswitch and HP Procurve wouldn't connect with fiber

Tags: networking, hp, fiber, trunk

the first thing that I don't understand is why the SMC switch considers the pair of single mode fibers as one port,one link, but the HP switch sees the two fibers as two ports.

when I wanted to configure the link from the SMC, I use : eth 1/1 for example.from the HP it was eth 1/11 and 1/12.

I have set the interface eth 1/1 duplex mode and speed to Auto and negotiate. when I connect to the HP I can configure the the eth 1/11 to auto for duplex-speed, but I can't do the same for the eth 1/12, the switch tells me that the port that Iam trying to configure with auto doesn't support it. and it says the same for every mode I try to configure it for. when I run the command show interfaces brief on the HP the speed and duplex mode for eth 1/12 are empty.

As a result : on HP eth 1/11 is up,but 1/12 is down. from the SMC side eth 1/1 is down.

what boggles my mind is when I run the command show interface counters on the SMC I see some ingoing and outgoing traffic !

none of the computers connected to the HP can communicate with the ones connected to the SMC.